# Scope issue in visual basic.net Unable to close stream object in finally clause ,getting System.NullReferenceException

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, .net-core

I have the following Visual Basic.Net 16.x Program

```
Module Program

    Sub Main(args As String())

        Dim sFileName As String = "VBnet_TextFileIO.txt"
        Dim sTextToWrite As String = "Hello From VB.net" + vbCrLf + "Second Line "

        Dim myFileStreamWriter As StreamWriter = Nothing

        Try
            myFileStreamWriter = New StreamWriter(sFileName, 'Pass the file path and name to the StreamWriter constructor.
                                                 True)      'Indicate that Append is True, so file will not be overwritten.

            myFileStreamWriter.WriteLine(sTextToWrite)

            myFileStreamWriter.Close() 'control do not reach here when exception occurs

        Catch ex As Exception

            Console.WriteLine("An Exception Occurred")

        Finally

            myFileStreamWriter.Close() 'Compiler says System.NullReferenceException: 
                                       'Object reference not set to an instance of an 
                                        object.'


        End Try

    End Sub

End Module
```

Under the Finally Clause

Compiler complains that "*System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
myFileStreamWriter was Nothing.*"

**Why is the compiler complaining like it?,**

**I am assuming that *myFileStreamWriter* is out of scope under the Finally clause section.
How should i rectify this?**

**How should i properly close the myFileStreamWriter object**

The exception happening under try section is System.UnauthorizedAccessException created by making the file read only by me to create the error condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the compiler doesn't tell you that at all. The compiler might give you a warning about a potential null reference but what you're reporting is a run-time exception.

The problem here is that the only line that can throw an exception in that `Try` block is the first one and, in that case, there will be no `StreamWriter` object created, in which case that variable will be `Nothing`. You can't close an object that was never created.

The code is poorly structured for a number of reasons. For one thing, you're calling `Close` in both the `Try` block and the `Finally` block. The whole point of a `Finally` block is to perform required cleanup, whether or not an exception is thrown. In your case, you would close the object twice if no exception was thrown. As there will be no object to close if an exception is thrown, you should call `Close` only in the `Try` block and do away with the `Finally` block.

It would be better still if you were to create the object with a `Using` statement, which guarantees disposal:

```vb
Try
    Using myFileStreamWriter = New StreamWriter(sFileName, 'Pass the file path and name to the StreamWriter constructor.
                                                True)      'Indicate that Append is True, so file will not be overwritten.
        myFileStreamWriter.WriteLine(sTextToWrite)
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine("An Exception Occurred")
End Try
```

It would be better still if you didn't create a `StreamWriter` yourself at all:

```vb
Try
    File.AppendAllText(sFileName, sTextToWrite)
Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine("An Exception Occurred")
End Try
```

Finally, you should pretty much never catch the `Exception` type. Only catch exceptions that you reasonably believe could be thrown, in which case you will know exactly what specific type they will be. You should also log the exception somewhere. You should then handle the `UnhandledException` event of the application to catch and log any unanticipated exceptions and shut down gracefully instead of crashing.